# broken image while resizing image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagelibrary

I am using image lib library of codeigniter to resize image. But resize function of image library produces broken image sometimes and also not getting any error. 
how to detect broken image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the answer.In Image_lib.php file go to line no 1259 and replace imagejpeg($resource,'', $this->quality); with imagejpeg($resource,NULL, $this->quality);
have a good day

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}
```

Comment: $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
   
 if(!$this->image_lib->resize())
 {
    
  echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
 }
return $this->image_lib->resize();

this is my code ,$this->image_lib->resize()  never returns false as well as not displaying proper image,it generates broken image